# How to write a jQuery to swap the text of two text elements in SVG tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have created the svg tag with two text elements.How can I write jquery in order to swap the contents of the elements with id txt1 and id txt2?

```
<svg id = "svg_box">
<text id = "txt1">hello</text>
<text id = "txt2">hi</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please post an example of the desired output along with what you've tried so far.

Comment: Would it not be easier to simply swap the position of the two elements?

Answer (score 1):

Just like that.

#### If you want to save HTML

```js
let txt1 = $('#txt1').html();
let txt2 = $('#txt2').html();
$('#txt1').html(txt2);
$('#txt2').html(txt1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<text id = "txt1">hello</text>
<text id = "txt2">hi</text>
```

#### If you want Text only

```js
let txt1 = $('#txt1').text();
let txt2 = $('#txt2').text();
$('#txt1').text(txt2);
$('#txt2').text(txt1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<text id = "txt1">hello</text>
<text id = "txt2">hi</text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to swap the content.

```
function swap_content(){
  var txt1 = $('#txt1').html();
  var txt2 = $('#txt2').html();
  $('#txt1').html(txt2);
  $('#txt2').html(txt1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy content of *item-1* into a temporary variable. Move content of *item-2* to *item-1*. Copy content of temporary variable to *item-2*.

```js
function switchText(selector1, selector2) {
  const el1 = $(selector1);
  const el2 = $(selector2);
  const tmp  = el1.text();
  el1.text(el2.text());
  el2.text(tmp);
}

switchText("#txt1","#txt2")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg id="svg_box" viewBox="0 0 120 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    svg { background-color: #eee; }
    .text { font: bold 20px sans-serif; }
    .upper { fill: darkorange; }
    .lower { fill: darkgreen; }
  </style>
  <text x="10" y="30" id="txt1" class="text upper">#1 hello</text>
  <text x="10" y="60" id="txt2" class="text lower">#2 hi there</text>
</svg>
```